# Is there any way to replace text in ChromiumBrowser like Chrome already has?

Tags: winforms, replace, cefsharp

I'm making a web editor application using CefSharp WinForms library, but I couldn't find a way to replace text from CefSharp API.
There is a find method in WebBrowserExtensions but no replace method.

Question 1:
Does anyone know where replacing text method is in CefSharp? 
Or there is no way to replace text in CefSharp? If yes, I need to find a detour for it.

Question 2:
There are yellow blocks marked found words when I try Find method, but those blocks are not a part of selection range of window object in HTML. Are those blocks made by native not web browser?

**Answer:**

I made "find and replace" function by myself using javascript, so if someone tries to do something like me then you can use below codes:

```js
var lastsearchedNodeIndex = -1;
var lastSearchedTextIndex = -1;
var lastRange = null;

function getTextLengthFromStartTo(targetNodeIndex) {
    var childNodes = editor.childNodes;
    var textLength = 0;
    if (targetNodeIndex >= childNodes.length) {
        return editor.textContent.length;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < targetNodeIndex; i++) {
        if (childNodes[i].textContent != null) {
            textLength += childNodes[i].textContent.length;
        }
    }
    return textLength;
}

function getCurrentCaretIndex() {
    var currentCaretIndex = 0;
    var doc = editor.ownerDocument || editor.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(editor);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            currentCaretIndex = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        }
    } else if ( (sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(editor);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        currentCaretIndex = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return currentCaretIndex;
}

function getCurrentNodeIndexAtCaret(caretIndex) {
    if (caretIndex == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    var currentNodeIndex = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < editor.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var frontTextLength = getTextLengthFromStartTo(i);
        var backTextLength = getTextLengthFromStartTo(i + 1);
        if (caretIndex > frontTextLength && caretIndex <= backTextLength) {
            currentNodeIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return currentNodeIndex;
}

function getCurrentTextIndexInNodexAtCaret(nodeIndex, caretIndex) {
    var textLength = getTextLengthFromStartTo(nodeIndex);
    var textIndex = caretIndex - textLength;
    return (textIndex < 0) ? 0 : textIndex;
}


function clearSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection().rangeCount > 0) {
        if (lastRange != null) {
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            lastRange.collapse(true);
            window.getSelection().addRange(lastRange);
        }
    }
}

function getTextNodesIn(node) {
    var textNodes = [];
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    } else {
        var children = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; ++i) {
            textNodes.push.apply(textNodes, getTextNodesIn(children[i]));
        }
    }
    return textNodes;
}

function setSelectionRange(el, start, end) {
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var textNodes = getTextNodesIn(el);
        var foundStart = false;
        var charCount = 0, endCharCount;

        for (var i = 0, textNode; textNode = textNodes[i++]; ) {
            endCharCount = charCount + textNode.length;
            if (!foundStart && start >= charCount && (start < endCharCount || (start == endCharCount && i <= textNodes.length))) {
                range.setStart(textNode, start - charCount);
                foundStart = true;
            }
            if (foundStart && end <= endCharCount) {
                range.setEnd(textNode, end - charCount);
                break;
            }
            charCount = endCharCount;
        }

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);

        lastRange = range;
        sel.anchorNode.parentElement.scrollIntoView();

    } else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", start);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

function findText(text, caseSensitive) {
    var currentCaretIndex = getCurrentCaretIndex();
    clearSelection();
    var regex;
    if (caseSensitive) {
        regex = text;
    } else {
        regex = new RegExp(text, "gi");
    }
    var childNodes = editor.childNodes;
    var startNodeIndex = getCurrentNodeIndexAtCaret(currentCaretIndex);
    var endNodeIndex = childNodes.length;
    var startTextIndex = 0;
    if (window.getSelection().focusOffset == 1) {
        startTextIndex  = lastSearchedTextIndex + 1;
    } else {
        startTextIndex = getCurrentTextIndexInNodexAtCaret(startNodeIndex, currentCaretIndex);
    }

    var searchedTextIndex = -1;
    var searchedNodeIndex = 0;
    var searchTargetSentence = null;
    var searchLoopCount = 0;

    if (currentCaretIndex == editor.textContent.length) {
        startNodeIndex = 0;
        startTextIndex = 0;
    }

    do 
    {
        for (var i = startNodeIndex; i < endNodeIndex; i++) {
            if (typeof (childNodes[i].textContent) == undefined || childNodes[i].textContent == null) {
                startTextIndex = 0;
                continue;
            }

            if (startTextIndex == childNodes[i].textContent.length) {
                startTextIndex = 0;
                continue;
            }

            if (startTextIndex > 0) {
                searchTargetSentence = childNodes[i].textContent.substring(startTextIndex, childNodes[i].textContent.length);
            } else {
                searchTargetSentence = childNodes[i].textContent;
            }
            searchedTextIndex = searchTargetSentence.search(regex);
            if (searchedTextIndex > -1) {
                searchedTextIndex += startTextIndex;
                searchedNodeIndex = i;
                break;
            }
            startTextIndex = 0;
        }

        if (searchedTextIndex == -1) {
            endNodeIndex = startNodeIndex + 1;
            startNodeIndex = 0;
            searchLoopCount++;
        }

    } while (searchLoopCount < 2 && searchedTextIndex == -1);

    lastsearchedNodeIndex = searchedNodeIndex;
    lastSearchedTextIndex = searchedTextIndex;

    if (searchedNodeIndex > -1 && searchedTextIndex > -1) {
        var textStartIndex = getTextLengthFromStartTo(searchedNodeIndex) + searchedTextIndex;
        setSelectionRange(editor, textStartIndex, textStartIndex + text.length);
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;

    }
}

function replaceText(textToFind, textToReplace, caseSensitive) {
    if (findText(textToFind, caseSensitive) == true) {
        var sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();
                range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(textToReplace));
            }
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            range = document.selection.createRange();
            range.text = textToReplace;
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no replace text method in CefSharp.

I think you have two options

1. Implement in javascript/html in the browser (DIY or something
   like [Tiny](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/full-featured/))
2. Manipulating the html from C# using GetSourceAsync and LoadHtml ([Documentation](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_OffScreen_ChromiumWebBrowser.htm))

Second question - I think you may be able to at least read the hits using the [FindHandler](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_FindHandler.htm). Have not tested this myself.

Comment: Thanks Ame. I should find a way by myself.